# ActionBarSherlock dependency issue after updating support libraries

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, actionbarsherlock

I updated some support libraries through the Android SDK manager, and now there is a conflict between what I assume is ActionBarSherlock and a support library. See below snippet of error.This is in Android Studio 1.2.2

```
C:\Android\Games\Copy of MyProject1\MyProject\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-wallet\7.5.0\res\values\wallet_colors.xml
Error:(1) Attribute "titleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "subtitleTextStyle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "divider" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "background" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "backgroundSplit" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "navigationMode" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "displayOptions" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "title" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "subtitle" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "icon" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "logo" has already been defined
Error:(1) Attribute "backgroundStacked" has already been defined
```

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:17'
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mdflip.areyoudrunk"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':ChartViewLib')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-xml:1.17.0-rc') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.google-play-services'
    }
}
```

I have tried removing the support library dependency, but that did not clear up the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, latest version of the Google Play services come with `appcompact-v7`. That means you won't be able to use both Play Services (latest version) and `ActionbarSherlock` in the same time. I'd suggest to migrate to `AppCompact` from `ABS` or not use the latest version of `Play Services`